# Group Theory - conjugation action on prime order groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given a finite group $G$ of order $p^n$ for some prime $p$. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. Show that there exists a $g \in G$\ $ H $  such that $g^{-1}Hg = H$.

We obviously know that $H$ is not normal and the centre of $G$ must be in $H$. I do not know where to go from here though. Looking for a solution and any additional information about methods to solve these types of problems

Comment: Why do you obviously know that H is not normal?

Comment: Sorry, that's not worded well - I  mean that if H is normal we can find a g that satisfies the conditions given by definition and so we want to restrict our attention to when H is not normal

Comment: You can edit what you wrote to improve it.

Comment: Use induction on $|G|$, and apply the inductive hypothesis to the subgroup $H/Z(G)$ of $G/Z(G)$.

Answer (score 0):

Corollary II.5.6 of the following book could help you

https://books.google.com/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&pg=PA92&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: What does the notation $N_G(H)$ represent?

Comment: The normalizer of H in G i.e. $\{x\in G | x^{-1}Hx=H\}$.